# Unable to store entered Input in Multiple Window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, toplevel, tkinter-button

I have created multiple windows and i want to print and store data entered in one of the TopLevel windows but it not able to store and print the data. The same thing when Iam doing without multiple windows,Iam able to do that. What can be wrong here, let me know.

```
from tkinter import *


def Read():
    name = namevalue.get()
    print('Name:',name)
    with open('attendance_data/detail.csv','a+') as f:
        f.write(name)

def New():
    top1 = Toplevel()

    top1.geometry('500x500')
    top1.resizable(False,False)
    top1.title('Existing Employee Details')
    
    l1 = Label(top1,text='New Employee Registeration',font='comicsans 14 bold',padx=10).grid(row = 0,column=3,pady=50)

    name = Label(top1,text='Name',padx=20)
    name.grid(row=1,column=2)
    namevalue = StringVar()
    nameEntry = Entry(top1,textvariable=namevalue).grid(row=1,column=3,pady=25)
    Button(top1,text='Submit',command=Read).grid(row=4,column=3,pady=25)  # command

    top1.mainloop()  

root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x500')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.title('Main Window')

l2 = Label(root,text='New Employee Registeration',font='comicsans 14 bold',padx=10).grid(row = 0,column=2,pady=50,padx=50)
b1 = Button(text='New Employee',bg='black',fg='red',font='comicsansms 12 bold',command=New).grid(row=10,column=2,pady=50)
b2 = Button(text='Existing Employee',bg='black',fg='red',font= 'comicsansms 12 bold').grid(row = 11,column=2,pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

I am able to print and store the entered data when iam not using Mutiple Windows

```
from tkinter import *

def Read():
    name = namevalue.get()
    print('Name:',name)
    with open('attendance_data/detail.csv','a+') as f:
        f.write(name)

root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x500')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.title('Main Window')

name = Label(root,text='Name',padx=20)
name.grid(row=1,column=2)
namevalue = StringVar()
nameEntry = Entry(root,textvariable=namevalue).grid(row=1,column=3,pady=25)
Button(root,text='Submit',command=Read).grid(row=4,column=3,pady=25)  # command

root.mainloop()
```

Help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `command` to the second button:

```
b2 = Button(..., command=Read).grid(row = 11,column=2,pady=50)
```

Thing to note is, you don't have to store the value in variable as the value of `b2` is `None`, so you might as well remove the variable.

**Edit:**
You need to make the entry, `namevalue`, a global variable so it can be accessed outside `New` and inside `Read` and other functions.

```
def New():
    global namevalue
    ....
```

Comment: @ Delrius i have edited out b2 button, it was part of other window i was making. Our problem still stands same

Comment: @VarunSingh I did not notice that, edited the answer